# Reorder columns based on a reference row in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataset where each row is a respondent, and columns represent the demographic profiles given to respondents. The dataset has the following form:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
opt1.A <- c("age", "place", "income", "gender")
res1.A <- c(18, "paris", 70000, "male")
opt1.B <- c("place", "age", "gender", "income")
res1.B <- c("london", 14, "female", 80000)
opt1.C <- c("gender", "income", "place", "age")
res1.C <- c("male", 10000, "milan", 24)
opt1.D <- c("income", "gender", "age", "place")
res1.D <- c(20000, "male", 24, "newyork")
res2.A <- c(23, "london", 75000, "male")
res2.B <- c("newyork", 34, "male", 15000)
res2.C <- c("female", 100000, "paris", 39)
res2.D <- c(30000, "female", 45, "rome")

beginning <- data.frame(id, opt1.A, res1.A, opt1.B, 
                   res1.B, opt1.C, res1.C, 
                   opt1.D, res1.D, res2.A, 
                   res2.B, res2.C, res2.D)

beginning
```

Each respondent is shown two profiles (1 and 2), each composed of four attributes (A, B, C, D). The issue is that attributes do not have a consistent order for each respondent, making complicating reshape function (i.e., respondent 1's order is age/place/gender/income while respondent 2's order is place/age/income/gender). I want to reorder the columns so each row has the same attribute order as row 1. The end dataset would thus look like this:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
opt1.A <- c("age", "age", "age", "age")
res1.A <- c(18, 14, 24, 24)
opt1.B <- c("place", "place", "place", "place")
res1.B <- c("london", "paris", "milan", "newyork")
opt1.C <- c("gender", "gender", "gender", "gender")
res1.C <- c("male","male",  "female", "male")
opt1.D <- c("income", "income", "income", "income")
res1.D <- c(20000,10000, 70000, 80000)
res2.A <- c(23, 34, 45, 39)
res2.B <- c("london", "newyork", "paris", "rome")
res2.C <- c("female", "female", "male", "male")
res2.D <- c(30000, 100000, 75000, 15000)

end <- data.frame(id, opt1.A, res1.A, opt1.B, 
                   res1.B, opt1.C, res1.C, 
                   opt1.D, res1.D, res2.A, 
                   res2.B, res2.C, res2.D)

end
```

Comment: I assume that's a typo in your sample data that you skip `res2.C` and have two copies of `res2.D`. I corrected that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'll correct it in the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does a pretty good job - all the values are sorted into the proper columns, but the columns aren't *quite* in the order you want as both `res1` and `res2` follow each `opt1` instead of having all the `res2` at the end.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

lookup = data.frame(
  attrib = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  opt1 = c("age", "place", "gender", "income")
)

beginning |>
  pivot_longer(
    -id, 
    names_sep = "\\.",
    names_to = c("type", "attrib")
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) |>
  select(-attrib) |>
  left_join(lookup, by = "opt1") |>
  arrange(id, attrib) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = attrib,
    values_from = c(opt1, res1, res2),
    names_sep = ".",
    names_vary = "slowest"
  ) |>
  mutate(across(matches("res.*[AD]$"), as.integer))
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#      id opt1.A res1.A res2.A opt1.B res1.B  res2.B  opt1.C res1.C res2.C opt1.D res1.D res2.D
#   <dbl> <chr>   <int>  <int> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <int>  <int>
# 1     1 age        18     23 place  london  newyork gender male   female income  20000  30000
# 2     2 age        14     34 place  paris   london  gender male   female income  10000 100000
# 3     3 age        24     45 place  milan   paris   gender female male   income  70000  75000
# 4     4 age        24     39 place  newyork rome    gender male   male   income  80000  15000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, with some manual work after this, I was able to get what I wanted!